# Checkable UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

i can't find a property to set my UIPickerView checkable... in other programs, I can select a item and the pickerView show a checkmark :-(

Comment: its a custom picker most likely

Answer (score 1):

Here I solve this problem by creating controller.With this we can able to design view with our own way.Here,I use a UITableView and some custom Delegates methods to create a picker view.

Hope,it solve your problem

Check this link also:

[Click here](http://dot-ios.blogspot.com/2012/10/create-custom-uipickerview-controller.html)!

Comment: why -1 ? please explain

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a custom picker view.  There is a method that is viewForPickerView:atComponent:row: or something like that.  You will need to return your own view and do your own logic to draw a checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

See  my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690792/creating-a-checkmark-inside-a-pickerview/7039462#7039462) for an elaboration of reproducing a checkmark-enabled UIPickerView, like the one Mobile Safari uses for dropdown menus.