# Creating a checkmark inside a Pickerview

Tags: iphone, customization, uipickerview

I am developing an application where i want to create a checkmark on the selected row by the user.

For Ex.

[image]

In UITableView there is 
         UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

But i am wondering is there something similar available for UIPickerView.

Any tutorial or pointer to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a UIPickerView subclass which can be used to implement this functionality. It forwards touch events to its superview and can therefore suppress the default behavior where entries are selected as they scroll past the middle.

The checkmark can be implemented by, as *pertert* writes, creating a custom UIView with an UIImageView and a UILabel for the pickerview's entries via the delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

You can find the project containing my subclass on [Github](https://github.com/thorfroelich/SLPickerView).

Comment: Its good.But still needs some improvement as it is showing 2 checkmark  when i scroll the picker up & down.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the repo with a fix. If you find more issues, please file an issue on Github instead of here.